# Integrating $\int \frac{dx}{x^{11}\sqrt{1+x^4}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

> Find $$I=\int \frac{dx}{x^{11}\sqrt{1+x^4}}$$

With $x^2=t$, we get $I=\int _{ }^{ }\frac{d\ \sqrt{t}}{\left(\sqrt{t}\right)^{11}.\sqrt{1+t^2}}=\frac{1}{2}\int _{ }^{ }\frac{dt}{t^6\sqrt{1+t^2}}$

Now, with $t= \tan k$ we get $I=\frac{1}{2}\int _{ }^{ }\frac{\cos ^5k.\ dk}{\sin ^6k}$ .

At this step, I can not do anything more. Can you show me the way to solve this?

I try to go with this way but it doesn't work.

Comment: Use the fundamental theorem of trigonometry and the substitution $\sin k=u$.

Comment: Try $t=\frac{1}{x^4}$ as a substitution instead

Comment: @Quippy  I try your way and get $-\frac{1}{4}\int _{ }^{ }\frac{t^2dt}{\sqrt{1+t}}$, what should I do next now? Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Integration by parts, of course!

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is surprisingly useful in solving these types of integrals. You can still integrate your way using [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cot%5E5+x+csc+x).

Comment: @Om3ga $\frac{d}{dt} \sqrt{t} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt t}$ so it all works out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After substituting $t = \frac{1}{x^4}$:

$$I = -\frac{1}{4} \int \frac{x^5 \ dt}{x^{11} \sqrt{1+x^4}} = -\frac{1}{4} \int \frac{t^2 x^2 \ dt}{\sqrt{x^4(t+1)}}= -\frac{1}{4}\int \frac{t^2 \ dt}{\sqrt{1+t}}.$$

Now further substitute $u = 1 + t$ and expand $t^2 = (u - 1)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$\frac12\int\frac{\cos(k)^5}{\sin(k)^6}\,\mathrm{d}k=\frac12\int\frac{\cos(k)^4}{\sin(k)^6}\cos(k)\,\mathrm{d}k=\frac12\int\frac{(1-\sin(k)^2)^2}{\sin(k)^6}\cos(k)\,\mathrm{d}k.$$ Let $u=\sin(k).$ Hence $$\frac12\int\frac{(1-\sin(k)^2)^2}{\sin(k)^6}\cos(k)\,\mathrm{d}k=\frac12\int\frac{(1-u^2)^2}{u^6}\,\mathrm{d}u.$$ You should be able to finish it here, since the rest is just algebra and using the power rule.

Comment: Why the downvote? My post answers the question directly and is legible and clear.